# Script to cause an ImportRange function to run on demand

Tags: google-apps-script

first, let me say, i am not a programmer, but i understand and can build spreadsheet ok. I'm newer to doing so in Google Sheets.   I am using an Importrange function to copy date from one spreadsheet tab to another spreadsheet.   I'm finding that there is a delay in the updating.  I checked my Settings for recalculations and Google Sheets is set to refresh when data is changed.   However, its not doing so.  So, i wanted to create a button the user can hit and force the ImportRange refresh.

I found some code that appears to accomplish this, but I can't get it to work:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').setValue('IMPORTRANGE('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123', 'sheet1!A:B')')
}
```

Here is my import range which is in CELL C4 of a sheet named CALCS:

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B5PEI5f4-TAhS77-poCYTiWI6w2t2BEzfiP5kXVq9lk/edit#gid=1661941505","PO TRACKING!A4:T1000")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of scripts! There is so much you can do with your projects when using Google Apps Script.

Your question is a good one but I took a different approach.  Rather than using an import range that needs to be recalculated, I just wrote a script that would do a similar thing.  If you need to collect a specific range of data instead of the entire sheet, then just make one small change to the script provided.

```
//CHANGE 
var poData = poTab.getDataRange().getValues();
//TO
var poData = poTab.getRange('INSERT A1 NOTATION HERE').getValues();
```

That should allow you to select a specifc range if needed.

```
    //TRANSFER DATA FROM ONE TAB TO ANOTHER
function transferFromSameSpreadsheet() {
  
  //GETS ACTIVE SPREADSHEET
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //GETS SPECIFIC SHEET BY NAME WHERE DATA IS STORED
  var poTab = ss.getSheetByName('Po Tracking');
  //STORES ALL DATA FROM SHEET
  var poData = poTab.getDataRange().getValues();
  //GETS SPECIFIC SHEET BY NAME WHERE DATA IS SENT
  var transferTo = ss.getSheetByName('insert sheet name here');
  //CLEARS OLD DATA
  transferTo.clearContents();
  //UPDATES SHEET WITH NEW DATA
  transferTo.getRange(1,1,poData.length,poData[0].length).setValues(poData);
  
  
}


//TRANSFER DATA FROM A MASTER SHEET TO ANOTHER WORKBOOK. RUN SCRIPT IN ACTIVE WORKBOOK, NOT MASTER.
function transferFromDifferentSpreadsheet() {
  
  //OPENS SPREADSHEET BY ID
  var ms = SpreadsheetApp.openById('insert spreadsheet id here');
  //GETS ACTIVE SPREADSHEET
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //GETS SPECIFIC SHEET BY NAME WHERE DATA IS STORED
  var poTab = ms.getSheetByName('Po Tracking');
  //STORES ALL DATA FROM SHEET
  var poData = poTab.getDataRange().getValues();
  //GETS SPECIFIC SHEET BY NAME WHERE DATA IS SENT
  var transferTo = ss.getSheetByName('insert sheet name here');
  //CLEARS OLD DATA
  transferTo.clearContents();
  //UPDATES SHEET WITH NEW DATA
  transferTo.getRange(1,1,poData.length,poData[0].length).setValues(poData);
  
}
```

Good luck!

Get range A1 notation documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is just setting the cell value as the string you input in the setValue()

If you want to input formula you can either include "=" when using setValue() or use setFormula() method

**Sample:**

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').setFormula('IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxx", "sheet1!A:B")');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('D1').setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxx", "sheet1!A:B")');
}
```

Note:

I also fixed the string format in your code so that it will provide a string input to the setValue() and setFormula()

**References:**

[Range.setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

[Range.setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)