# Import Range Apps Script Code for specific cells transfer between 2 work books

Tags: google-apps-script

As told by someone here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258767/17862862

in this answer, A1 notation dosent seem to work for specified range :
var poData = poTab.getDataRange(**'Incoming Sample!A1:B10'**).getValues();

But the a1 notation is causing error,
without this the code is working fine and importing the whole sheet, which i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use the method `SpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Incoming Sample").getRange("A1:B10")`

Following Google Documentation for the `Sheet.getDataRange()` method, it has to be called on a `Sheet` Object, and does not accept any arguments. **It returns all non-empty cells in a Sheet**.

That being said, you can get a specific range using the method `Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)`.

So your code would be something like this:

```
//I am assuming your variable poTab represents the Sheet 'Incoming Sample'
//Please let me know if I am mistaken
var poData = poTab.getRange('A1:B10').getValues();
```

If poTab is not the Sheet you want to extract the values from:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() // Gets the active Spreadsheet into a variable
var poData = ss.getSheetByName("Incoming Sample").getRange('A1:B10').getValues();
```

Useful resources:

- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)